# Put text in between two images

Tags: css

I am not good at css. How to put text nicely in between images?
And it should work even when the screen size is smaller (like on iphone browser) [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/4ya5t8ne/2/)
[image]

```html
<div class="testimonials-list">
  <div id="quote-7728" class="quote first individual-testimonial">
    <img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50" src="http://placehold.it/75x100" alt="" />TEXT HERE TEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE
    <img width="50" height="50" class="avatar " src="http://placehold.it/75x100" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
<!--/.testimonials-list-->
```

Comment: That looks like a one row, three cell, table.   No CSS need apply.

Comment: @SteveWellens Bad advice. Tables are for tabular data, not for styling.

Comment: @str It **is** tabular data.  One row, three cells.  It is not styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox`

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, est.
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
</div>
```

Comment: my images becomes so small 3px x 3px when views on iphone. Maybe it conflicts with the theme css?

Comment: You can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/265/ what happens when you resize window, images will change size, but if you don't want that you can set fixed size on images like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/264/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with bootstrap

Just add the classes:

```
<div class="testimonials-list container">
        <div id="quote-7728" class="quote first individual-testimonial row">
            <img width="50" height="50" class="avatar avatar-50 col-md-3 col-xs-3" src="http://placehold.it/75x100" alt="" />
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            TEXT HERE TEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE
            </div>
            <img width="50" height="50" class="avatar col-md-3 col-xs-3" src="http://placehold.it/75x100" alt="" />
        </div>
</div><!--/.testimonials-list-->
```

[See JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18517/)